# C# ASP.NET Core building dynamic forms

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, office365, asp.net-core-1.0

I want to implement something similar like SharePoint online does and that is the list functionality. I want to create dynamic lists add new columns, etc. The user can fill in the form and save the data.

The bottle neck is the database, I have some hard time understand how this should be built.

I was thinking to create dynamic SQL Server tables, columns, etc, but maybe this is not the good approach. Can somebody advise on how the database should look like?

I was thinking about creating one table called `Lists` and there store List properties. Then a many to many relation to another table called `Fields` where I can store all fields related to a specific form. Many to many relation because some fields are common for all forms like: Id, CreatedBy, Created, Modified, ModifiedBy, etc. Now comes the difficult part. Where should I store the actual data? Should I create another table called `FormData` and store in there the data? And what relation should it have with `Lists` and `Fields` tables?

Comment: At least you should throw one example.what kind of form user will fill ?

Comment: @KumarHarsh: The form is dynamic, as I mentioned there will be some common fields that will be auto-filled by the system (Id, CreatedDate, Createdby, etc).Otherwise the form should be dynamic and that means the customer can add fields (textbox, checkbox, dropwdown, textarea, datetime, etc)

Comment: No matter ,how dynamic you want to create,it has to follow some specific domain and biz rule.For example there is lot of diff between registration form of School and Tender portal.It can't be both.impossible.Also say same school software can be customize for 1000 schools and each of their requirement vary.That do not mean it is fit for tender portal or it is 100% dynamic.

Comment: @KumarHarsh: The business rule is simple: Allow customer to create and customize forms. By that I mean imagine an excel file. In my example the sheet from excel is the form and the columns in excel are the fields in my form. in one sheet you can create a table with 10 columns where you store Customer information. You can add more fields or remove fields except the default ones (Id, CreatedBy,CreatedDate, etc). Then you crate another sheet and you store Employees details, also you can customize the amount of columns. Now I want to implement same logic to allow customer create forms on the fly.

Comment: Guess you hvn't understood my school vs Tender example.Employee data of school or Tender porta or it can be anything.While letting user create dynamic form is ok,but the that software as whole has to follow certain domain i.e. biz rule. Ok in one UI I allow user to Create table or Alter table.Then accordingly in another UI which is dynamic Employee UI allow userto fill Employee data.That means allow user to Create new field or alter in one UI then accordingly create dynamic UI in another.So for each Client you diff DB. While taking inspiration from Excel is ok,it can't be 100% Excel.

Comment: @KumarHarsh: If you are familiar with SharePoint you know what I mean. The idea is the same. Customers can create their own lists where they can store the data they need/want, customize the list form fields, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NoSql approach seems to be a simple one. If you think about databases only as IO devices, which shouldn't contain any "business" logic, the fact that memory cost and memory reading/writng time(SSD) become lower - you will have little bid more options for your issue.

For example you can save field's collection in one object

```
{
    "key": "form1",
    "fields" : [ "Id", "CreatedAt" ]
}
```

Based on that object you can generate view with list or form of created fields.
You can introduce own "object" for field with more data you need for view generation and for data processing.

```
{
    "key": "form1",
    "fields" : [ 
        { "Name": "Id", "Type": "string" }, 
        { "Name" "CreatedAt", "Type": "DateTime" } 
    ]
}
```

The actual data can be saved in one object too

```
{
    "formKey": "form1",
    "Name": "FirstName LastName",
    "CreatedAt": "2017-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"
}
```

On client side this data can be easily saved as json object and sended to the server.
On server side you can deserialize that object as `Dictionary<string, object>` and handle it in dynamic way

```
var formEntity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(requestBody);

var name = formEntity["Name"].ToString();
```

If you tightly attached to the relational database, you can save "raw json" in NVARCHAR column and one identity column.
For processing data you will be able to deserialize it to the `Dictionary<string, object>`.
With field object `{ "Name" "CreatedAt", "Type": "DateTime" }` you can convert values to the expected types for correct validation and processing.

You will be able to search for data based on dynamic fields ro create dynamic reports, where user can create his own reports.

Because structure of fields not dynamic you can save forms and fields structure in relational way. Below is my suggestion for sql server database.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Forms (
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Field(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Name NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    TypeName NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, -- Or INT -> can represent SqlDbType enum in c#
)

-- many to many relation of Form and Fields
CREATE TABLE FormFields (
    FormId INT NOT NULL,
    FieldId INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (FormId, FieldId)
)

-- because data is "dynamic" it should be saved  as string (json format)
CREATE TABLE FormData(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    FormId INT NOT NULL,
    Data NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, -- json format
)
```

And consider to use Microsoft version of NoSql - [DocumentDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-introduction)

Comment: Thank's for your answer. In the case of NoSql, you mentioned that user can search data, how will that work more exactly? NoSql sound's a good approach I am wondering about one thing: If I create a lookup type of field that will allow user to get data from another field in another form, how will that work from relation point of view? Deleting the data from the source list, etc?

Comment: For relations between forms different forms you can introduce some kind of "aggregate" forms, which contains few forms. Based on your comments, you want build dynamic database. So use same approach as excel, but instead of saving "sheet schema" to the file, you will save it to the database.  With this kind of approach all relations between forms and data should be handled in the code(c#), not in database. Consider database as excel file.

Answer (score 3):

I would structure it like the following pseudo-SQL (table names in bold):

**Lists:**

```
Id int
Name nvarchar(255)  -- list name
CreatedBy, Created, Modified, ModifiedBy (audit for the List creation/changes)
```

**ListFields:**

```
Id int
ListId int  -- foreign key to associated list
Name nvarchar(255)  -- column name
DataType nvarchar(3) -- abbreviation of data type - string, integer, float, bool etc.
Sort int -- column order
CreatedBy, Created, Modified, ModifiedBy (audit for List Field creation/changes)
```

That defines the lists themselves.

Now when the user enters data...

**ListEntries:** (groups the data entered - would be a record per row if these are columns in a table, or a single record for data entered into a form)

```
Id int
ListId int  -- foreign key to associated list
CreatedBy, Created, Modified, ModifiedBy (audit for Data creation/changes)
```

**ListValues:** (actual data entered into each field)

```
Id int
ListEntryId int  -- foreign key to the associated group of values
ListFieldId int  -- foreign key to associated field
Value nvarchar(max)  -- data (stored as text regardless of whether text or not - it could be int, double etc.)
```

Personally I wouldn't try to recycle common fields.  Having the audit fields on each table gives a fine grain to change tracking (if needed) and is easy to follow when looking at the records. I left auditing off the individual values because often it is sufficient to track changes as a collection (via `ListEntries`). Of course, auditing could exist here too if desired.

Comment: Also If you need to permit deleting columns that already have data you could implement `IsDeleted`, `Deleted`, & `DeletedBy`. Then do a soft delete by setting `IsDeleted` to true. That's what I have done in the past.